# React native android crashes on device during animations

Tags: android, animation, react-native, crash

Running RN v0.40.0 on a Physical device on Android 5.1. I'm trying to animate a text to appear with fade-in and slide up in the following way:

```
export default class Example extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.translate = new Animated.Value(-15);
    this.fade = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Animated.timing(this.translate, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 800,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
      }).start();
      Animated.timing(this.fade, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 800,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }
      ).start();
    }, 150);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            transform: [
              {translateY: this.translate},
            ],
            opacity: this.fade
          }}
        >
            <Text>
              {this.props.text}
            </Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

And after I reload JS bundle from the dev menu and go to that view app crashes with no error log, sometimes showing `Application ... stopped working`, sometimes not. If I start the app from the android menu again it loads ok, crashes only for the first time. It definitely has something to do with animations since before I introduced animations I had no crashes. There are no logs, no clues, please, give me some advice what could that be and what should I try and what should I check. Thanks.

Btw, on that view with animations I have a pretty heavy background image (~400k) could that be a problem?

**UPD**: I have narrowed it down to that it crashes when I'm trying to run animations in parallel, either with `setTimeout` or with `Animation.parallel`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Facing the same issue now. Crashing on android with parallel animations.

Comment: @ErikHaiderForsén facing the same issue. It seems to have reappeared recently. Did you find the source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's causing the crash, but using Animated.parallel has worked for me:

```
        Animated.parallel([
        Animated.spring(
            this.state.pan, {
                ...SPRING_CONFIG,
                overshootClamping: true,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                toValue: {x: direction, y: -200}
            }),
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.fadeAnim, {
                toValue: 1,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                duration: 750,
            }),
       ]).start();
```

where SPRING_CONFIG is something like

```
var SPRING_CONFIG = {bounciness: 0, speed: .5};//{tension: 2, friction: 3, velocity: 3};
```

and pan and fadeAnim values are set in the constructor this.state values as:

```
        pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
        fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
```

with the animated View as

```
<Animated.View style={this.getStyle()}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, {color: this.state.textColor}]}>{this.state.theText}</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

and the getStyle function is

```
    getStyle() {
     return [
          game_styles.word_container,
          {opacity: this.state.fadeAnim},
          {transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()}
        ];
     }
```

[This tutorial](http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-animated-api-with-panresponder/) helped me set this up...good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful info. But unfortunately, I had crashes even if animated only one element at a time...

Comment: In the docs they initialize the Animated.Value as `this.state = { pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),};` --no argument in the parenths; not sure if your negative value is an issue

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not the issue